# Seared my circuit while checking voltage

Tags: pcb, multimeter, short-circuit

I was attempting to diagnose a problem with my dvd player as I was not getting any power, I wanted to use my multi-meter to see where the circuit was shorting out, I set the setting on the multi-meter to the 200V reading and placed the nodes in the correct configuration, however when I placed them on a component sparks started flying everywhere, I seared the pcb and I ended up wrecking the circuit. I don't understand where I went wrong though, how do you properly check the circuit with a multi-meter without shorting both the board and your meter. Asking as a noob. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Were your leads plugged into the Voltage jacks ("V"), or the Current jacks ("A", "mA") of your meter? The current jacks cause a short circuit...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally short something when you put the meter probes on the board? If you didn't, and the meter was set to a voltage scale, and the probes were in the correct jacks, and the meter was not broken, then you should not have seen sparks fly.

Comment: I had the meter probes on a diode set to the correct sides, my jacks may have been in the current slots though I can't remember. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tape the exposed probe metal surfaces with Heatshink or tape so only the tips are exposed.  This reduces the risk of unintended shorts, with high voltage exposed leads on parts < 200V.  It's pretty easy to have these accidents. Now you are wiser. If there's no space to probe, don't.

They do have tiny spring clip cables for grabbing dual inline chip pins which are available in some places like Electronic part stores, which is also an option, then power up after connection.

Comment: "If there's no space to probe, don't." Well said :)